# Why is my Matchers.equalTo() saying the array is different when it the same

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The code below is giving be an error I cant really understand

I am using Junit to test a spring boot controller, the test should use mocked data but when I try to check the data that gets returned it fails even though the data is the same

```
@WebMvcTest
public class ProductGetControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private QueryForProductsService queryForProductsService;

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private Set<String> listMarkets1 = new HashSet<>();

    private Set<String> listTechnologies1 = new HashSet<>();

    public ProductGetControllerTests(){
        this.listMarkets1.add("Music listener market");
        this.listMarkets1.add("Retailers");
        this.listTechnologies1.add("Java");
        this.listTechnologies1.add("Angular");
    }

    @Test
    void testGettingAllProductsWithControllersWithMockedData() throws Exception {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

        products.add(new Product("id", "Test Name", "description",this.listMarkets1, this.listTechnologies1));


        Mockito.when(queryForProductsService.searchForProductsWithNameOnly("")).thenReturn(products);


        mockMvc.perform(get("/products")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(jsonPath("$", Matchers.hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", Matchers.equalTo("id")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].productName", Matchers.equalTo("Test Name")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].targetMarketStack", Matchers.equalTo(new JSONArray(listMarkets1))));
    }
}
```

Error that shows up:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$[0].targetMarketStack"
Expected: <["Music listener market","Retailers"]>
     but: was <["Music listener market","Retailers"]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `JSONArray` doesn't override method `equals`, and the implementation of `equals` from Object is called, which simply compares references.
And you create new JSONArray object, passing same arguments, that is the reference to it will be different from the one created by the framework.

Comment: Can use `Matchers.contains(listMarkets1)` instead of `Matchers.equalTo(new JSONArray(listMarkets1)))`